# Middleware.ts "req" problem: - No overload matches this call

Tags: typescript, next.js, middleware, next-auth

I am using

```json
"next": "14.1.0",
"next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.11",
"next-themes": "^0.2.1",
```

I have a middleware.ts file in the root of my project directory

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import authConfig from "@/auth.config";

const { auth } = NextAuth(authConfig);
export default auth((req) => {
  const { nextUrl } = req;
  const isLoggedIn = !!req.auth;
```

Although the code is running, I have this problem shown to me when I hover over auth((req) =>

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 4, '(args_0: GetServerSidePropsContext): Promise<Session | null>', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(req: NextAuthRequest) => Response | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GetServerSidePropsContext'.
> Overload 2 of 4, '(args_0: (req: NextAuthRequest) => void | Response | Promise<void | Response>): AppRouteHandlerFn', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(req: NextAuthRequest) => Response | null' is not assignable to parameter of type '(req: NextAuthRequest) => void | Response | Promise<void | Response>'.
> Type 'Response | null' is not assignable to type 'void | Response | Promise<void | Response>'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'void | Response | Promise<void | Response>'

I have also have
a middleware header displaying repeatedly for no reason:
`{ x-middleware-next: '1' }`

I have tried to uninstall `node_modules` are `npm install` again, however the persists.

Check the documentation or source code for NextAuth to understand what type of argument it expects, but I didn't want is cause this. Even If someone has an idea of where I should start looking it would be a great help.

I also did `console.log({req})` and got this:

```js
req: {
  cookies: RequestCookies {"authjs.csrf-token":{"name":"authjs.csrf-token","value":"c8dfb5614431b2fa1cd54685882c2af8d60fa34d133c21ae51632495|20282a68d3490d2d7c4a7c2db262dfcbfbedb3f6f9dffb30091b2e27fcee3d34"},"authjs.callback-url":{"name":"authjs.callback-url","value":"http://localhost:3001/settings"},"authjs.session-token":{"name":"authjs.session-token","value":"eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJQ0JDLUhTNTEyIiwia2lkIjoiN3g5RFVNVmFFVTZnaWFiMGwwT1dEdDRlNFNzUkhfY2J3TW9mMkV6RXl5Nm9uSzVvOHhTUFBCNzk5UlZvcW0ydjZ6Njc0a1FDdjlqb20yVDhTLWExZFEifQ..crYYxyQpHJCdabnFQpFpWg.YHE2kxY29kNap8pAADLW7rAIqa58upu7SG-yph1HEMXiXvgyM681Pq5461t0SorPlTd-cCLsNmmMsCZQiPQrq_O8MLytzgJKLWiLRL6kR-y20NqswZgeq1sVg6uTjkgUhjY8_8LXDUQ2bcN795pqJLHqwz2QHeA9NVrTGAZs2qEwEfj8i2FNfBNdLhNFEWu3dduZrpM4SvRmr3UuWF8Cv2MUsKVOWdcbvRM4d8gbLoudKGj8MgK_-TeE_TVmELGA07S9YaPxLPdm6-jylw.MUPezthIaZ6-cOgyZSmao6mq1XsBU2WcpiqFIs"}},
  geo: {},
  ip: undefined,
  nextUrl: {
  href: 'http://localhost:3001/api/auth/session',
  origin: 'http://localhost:3001',
  protocol: 'http:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: 'localhost:3001',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: '3001',
  pathname: '/api/auth/session',
  search: '',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams {  },
  hash: ''
},
  url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/auth/session',
  bodyUsed: false,
  cache: 'default',
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  destination: '',
  headers: {
  accept: '*/*',
  accept-encoding: 'gzip, deflate, br',
  accept-language: 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  cache-control: 'no-cache',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  content-type: 'application/json',
  cookie: 'authjs.csrf-token=c8dfb5614431b2fa1cd54685882c2af45fb1bd28d60fa34d133c21ae51632495%7C20282a68d3490d2d7c4a7c2db262dfcbfbedb3f6f9dfe27fcee3d34; authjs.callback-url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3001%2Fsettings; authjs.session-token=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2Q0JDLUhTNTEylkIjoiN3g5RFVNVmFFVTZnaWFiMGwwT1dEdDRlNFNzUkhfY2J3TW9mMkV6RXl5Nm9uSzVvOHhTUFBCNzk5UlZvcW0ydjZ6Njc0a1FDdjlqb20yVDhTLWExZFEifQ..crYYxyQpHJCdabnFQpFpWg.YHE2kxY29kNap8pAADLW7rAIqa58upu7SG-yph1HEMXiXvgyM681Pq5461t0SorPlTd-cCLsNmmMsCZQiPQrq_O8MLytzgJKLWiLRL6kR-y20NqswZgeq1sVg6uTjkgUhjY8_8LXDUQ2bcQ23sN795pqwz2QHeA9NVrTGAZs2qEwEfj8i2FNfBNdLhNFEWu3dduZrpM4SvRmr3UuWF8Cv2MUsKVOWdcbvRM4d8gbLoudKGj8MgK_-TeE_TVmELGA07S9YaPxLPdm6-jylw.MUPezthIaZ6-cOgyZSmao6mq1XsBUjRbAQ2WcpiqFIs',
  dnt: '1',
  host: 'localhost:3001',
  pragma: 'no-cache',
  referer: 'http://localhost:3001/settings',
  sec-ch-ua: '"Not A(Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="121", "Chromium";v="121"',
  sec-ch-ua-mobile: '?0',
  sec-ch-ua-platform: '"macOS"',
  sec-fetch-dest: 'empty',
  sec-fetch-mode: 'cors',
  sec-fetch-site: 'same-origin',
  user-agent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  x-forwarded-for: '::1',
  x-forwarded-host: 'localhost:3001',
  x-forwarded-port: '3001',
  x-forwarded-proto: 'http'
},
  integrity: '',
  keepalive: false,
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'cors',
  redirect: 'follow',
  referrer: 'about:client',
  referrerPolicy: '',
  signal: AbortSignal {
  [Symbol(kEvents)]: SafeMap(0) {},
  [Symbol(events.maxEventTargetListeners)]: 10,
  [Symbol(events.maxEventTargetListenersWarned)]: false,
  [Symbol(kHandlers)]: SafeMap(0) {},
  [Symbol(kAborted)]: false,
  [Symbol(kReason)]: undefined,
  [Symbol(kOnabort)]: undefined,
  [Symbol(realm)]: {
  settingsObject: {
  baseUrl: undefined,
  origin: [Getter],
  policyContainer: { referrerPolicy: 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin' }
}
}
}
}
```

Can someone please me understand what is going on in this `(req)` and to fix the middleware issue? I think I have provided the necessary details if need something else I can provide it to the assistant, Please ask!

**Side note (probably not important):** There was an issue with `update()` in `node_modules/next-auth/index.d.ts`,

In the end, it had:

```js
export default function NextAuth(config: NextAuthConfig | ((request: NextRequest | undefined) => NextAuthConfig)): NextAuthResult;
```

Upon updating data my client side was updating while the Server side was not updating. So I change it to:

```js
export default function NextAuth(config: NextAuthConfig): NextAuthResult;
```

This is a side note because the `auth((req) =>` problem has been there even before I made the change.

Comment: r u using `getServerSideProps` somewhere. because this indicates "    Argument of type '(req: NextAuthRequest) => Response | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GetServerSidePropsContext'.
"

Comment: Got a similar issue after following Antonios guide on YT. If you followed the same tutorial change the return null(s) to just a simple return. After the update the function signature you're using for the middleware does not match what the new auth package expects... so do this if you don't wanna downgrade from auth beta.9+

Comment: i am wondering how do i get urlParam from the request?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you do not return "null"
Just `return` instead of `return null`

Comment: But why? Could you tell me more about the issue?

Comment: This is what the function expects
it's **typescript**
Although `return null` is acceptable
But **NextAuth** specifies the return method
Why do they do that? I don't know

Answer (score 0):

I was able to eliminate the error with this:

```js
 import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

 // code...

 return NextResponse.next()
```